# Yii2 phone field issue

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, active-form

Here is my table

```
id           int (primary_key)
name         varchar
contact_no   int
date         date
```

Model rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['contact_no'], 'integer'],
    ];
}
```

View

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-info', 'layout' => 'horizontal']); ?>

    ...

    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'contact_no') ?>

    ...

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

When I save the number (e.g. 9999999999), it saves it as **2147483647** in the table. I inspect form post and its the same value I am passing in form but it saves different.

Tell me if I am doing it wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using a signed INT for this column, in MySQL this type is stored on 4 bytes : from `-2147483647` to `2147483647`.

You should use unsigned INT, or simply VARCHAR.

Read more : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Thanks, using varchar instead int helped.

Comment: @Ankit using a varchar is also useful for the end user as phone numbers can be entered in different formats e.g `+123456789098`, `+(123) 456 789 098`, `123-456-7890`

Answer (score 3):

it is Your Database contains . please check if Your Database supports 9999999999.Because database column may not support 10 digit.. increase your column size